# Compilation warning: no rule to process file of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture i386

Tags: c, xcode, curl, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm trying to build `libcurl` as `static` library for `iOS` with `xcode 4.2 + sdk 5.0` on `OSX 10.6.8` with `apple llvm compiler 3.0 or LLVM GCC 4.2.`

It compiled successfully (with both compilers) but has many `warnings` like this:

```
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../../ProjectName/Libs/curl-7.26.0/src/tool_bname.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture i386
```

I checked `target->Compile Sources`. it has all `.c` files that needs and don't have any
`.h` files.

I also tried to change `Compile Sources` As to `C` but is no take any effect.

I'm not understand how to fix it and why type of C sources is a `sourcecode.c.c`

Comment: Since they're only warnings, maybe it's OK to ignore them.

Comment: @KennethHoste: "no rule to process file", it seems that some files was not compiled; the lib might miss some functionalities. Looks like an autotools / make issue.